# JSON from PHP to javascript

Tags: php, ajax, html, bootstrap-modal

I received a array in json. How can I get values with bucle for in javascript?.
If array json hasn't assign a variable name

I have a array in php which convert to json

```
 echo json_encode($error);
```

I get the json following:

[image: json image]

values in json

```
["El nombre del usuario no puede estar vacio","La contrase\u00f1a debe tener un m\u00ednimo de
 7 caracteres"]
```

How can I get data in javascript my function ajax

```
      function submitForm()
        {
            var dataString = $("#userForm").serialize();
            console.log(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/altausers",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(text)
                {
                   if(text==='success')
                   {

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $("#error").removeClass('hidden'); 
#get values json here



                   }
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to specify

```
dataType: 'json'
```

then, your data would be in a javascript array:

```
function submitForm()
    {
        var dataString = $("#userForm").serialize();
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/altausers",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(text)
            {
               if(text.length > 0) {
               $.each(text,function(index,value) {
                    alert('Response: '+ value);
               }

            }
        });

}
```

However, you would have to make sure that php ALWAYS returns a json-encoded response... even if you do it manually like:

```
<?php echo "[success]"; ?>
```

In javascript, you would just test

```
if(text[0] == 'success') { //hurray!!
}
```

Comment: Technically you don't _have_ to specify `dataType: 'json'` if you're sending a `Content-type: application/json` header.

Comment: @h2ooooooo you're right. Additionally, other mime types can be sent which will produce a different data result (if you do not use `dataType`). see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

PHP has method known as json_encode and json_decode which can me used to handle json data in php, while the json data can be directly accessed in javascript so I think you should look into that